# Save multiple associated entities in one go Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i've an Order that saves, but the multiple orderlines (a product and total price, quantity) for each order isnt saving together with the order.

Here is the log dump at this stage:

```
{ "associated": [ "Orderlines", "Payments" ], "Orderlines": [ { "total_cost": "222.44", "total_quantity": "2", "product_variants_id": "34" }, { "total_cost": "154", "total_quantity": "2", "product_variants_id": "33" } ], "users_id": 1, "usersaddress_id": 1, "orderstatus": 0, "date": "2017-09-21T01:53:38+00:00", "last_modified": "2017-09-21T01:53:38+00:00" }
```

Controller:

```
$associated = ['Orderlines', 'Payments'];
    $order = $this->Orders->newEntity(['associated'=>$associated]);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $order = $this->Orders->patchEntity($order, $this->request->getData());
        $order->users_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        //Hardcoded the SHU MART stores location because thats all thats gonna get implemented for now
        $order->usersaddress_id = 1;
        $order->orderstatus = 0;
        $order->date = Time::now();
        $order->last_modified = Time::now();

        //god this is ugly. forgive me for i have sinned
        $order->setDirty('users_id', true);
        $order->setDirty('usersaddress_id', true);
        $order->setDirty('date', true);
        $order->setDirty('last_modified', true);
        $order->setDirty('orderlines', true);
        if ($this->Orders->save($order)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The order has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'orderlines','action' => 'index']);

        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The order could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
```

and the form inside the orderline loop:

```
 <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('Orderlines.'.$orderLineIndex.'.total_cost',
                        ['label'=>'', 'value'=>$product_total
                            , 'type'=>'hidden'
                        ]);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('Orderlines.'.$orderLineIndex.'.total_quantity',
                        ['label'=>'', 'value'=>$item['quantity']
                            , 'type'=>'hidden'
                        ]);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('Orderlines.'.$orderLineIndex.'.product_variants_id',
                        ['label'=>'', 'value'=>$item['id']
                            , 'type'=>'hidden'
                        ]);
                    ?>
```

Now i've tried it without `Orderlines.` at the start, and tried saving each orderline individually but it wont save the order id and stuff.

I just want to be able to save it in one go. Something like:

```
order{ id, x, y, orderlines[[0]{OL1...}[1]{OL2}] }
```

So i can have as many orderlines in an order and save them all together each time. I think im just missing a small syntax thing, but maybe im not.

```
    public 'associated' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Orderlines' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Payments' (length=8)
  public 'orderlines' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[349]
          public 'total_cost' => float 40.28
          public 'total_quantity' => int 1
          public 'product_variants_id' => int 679
          public '[new]' => boolean true
          public '[accessible]' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public '[dirty]' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public '[original]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[virtual]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[errors]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[invalid]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[repository]' => string 'Orderlines' (length=10)
      1 => 
        object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[375]
          public 'total_cost' => float 66
          public 'total_quantity' => int 2
          public 'product_variants_id' => int 55
          public '[new]' => boolean true
          public '[accessible]' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public '[dirty]' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public '[original]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[virtual]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[errors]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[invalid]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[repository]' => string 'Orderlines' (length=10)
      2 => 
        object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[347]
          public 'total_cost' => float 222.44
          public 'total_quantity' => int 2
          public 'product_variants_id' => int 34
          public '[new]' => boolean true
          public '[accessible]' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public '[dirty]' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          public '[original]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[virtual]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[errors]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[invalid]' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public '[repository]' => string 'Orderlines' (length=10)
  public 'users_id' => int 1
  public 'usersaddress_id' => int 1
  public 'orderstatus' => int 0
  public 'date' => 
    object(Cake\I18n\Time)[327]
      public 'time' => string '2017-09-27T21:12:38+10:00' (length=25)
      public 'timezone' => string 'Australia/Melbourne' (length=19)
      public 'fixedNowTime' => boolean false
  public 'last_modified' => 
    object(Cake\I18n\Time)[350]
      public 'time' => string '2017-09-27T21:12:38+10:00' (length=25)
      public 'timezone' => string 'Australia/Melbourne' (length=19)
      public 'fixedNowTime' => boolean false
  public '[new]' => boolean true
  public '[accessible]' => 
    array (size=3)
      '*' => boolean true
      'id' => boolean false
      'users_id' => boolean false
  public '[dirty]' => 
    array (size=7)
      'associated' => boolean true
      'orderlines' => boolean true
      'users_id' => boolean true
      'usersaddress_id' => boolean true
      'orderstatus' => boolean true
      'date' => boolean true
      'last_modified' => boolean true
  public '[original]' => 
    array (size=1)
      'orderlines' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[359]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[372]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(App\Model\Entity\Orderline)[346]
              ...
  public '[virtual]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public '[errors]' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
     public '[invalid]' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public '[repository]' => string 'Orders' (length=6)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Association properties are by default lowercase and underscored unless explicitly configured otherwise, ie `Orderlines != orderlines`.

Comment: Im afraid that didnt work, i had made some changes, now creating multiple orderlines entities and putting it inside orders. Please find the `var_dump` of $order edited into the post. Im sure its something really little!

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 answers i got. The first being the really-messy-but-works solution, and the one i found later.

```
if ($result) {
        $orderlinescontroller = new OrderlinesController();
        if ($orderlinescontroller->addAllFromCart($result->id)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The order ' . $result->id . ' has been successfully placed'));
            $this->clearUsersCart($this->Auth->user('id'));
```

so first you save the order, then create an instance of the controller of the associated item you need to save multiple of. Then i created a function that looks at the db/session variables for the cart items to save them with the order.

```
public function addAllFromCart($order_id)
    {
        $success = true;
        $cart_items = $this->getCartItemsArray();
        $saved_ids = [];
        foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
            $this->log($cart);
            $orderline = $this->makeEntity($order_id, $cart);
            $new = $this->Orderlines->save($orderline);
            if ($new) {
                $this->log('Line saved');
                array_push($saved_ids, $new->id);
            } else {
                $this->log('Line save FAILED');
                $success = false;

                //if there is a failure, we need to delete the lines that we made - there is a better way, but cake sucks and conventions don't work
                foreach ($saved_ids as $id_to_delete) {
                    $d = $this->Orderlines->get($id_to_delete);
                    $this->Orderlines->delete($d);
                }

            }
        }
        $this->log('WAS ADD ALL FROM CART A SUCCESS? -- ' . $success);
//        if ($success) {
//            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
//        } else {
//            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
//        }

        return $success;
    }
`
```

which altogether is super messy and un-cake-ey but it works. The other solution i found out much later when i revisited a part of adding products, was how it explicitly told save() what associations to save. Hence the below was used.

`$result = $this->Orders->save($save, ['associated' => ['Orderlines']]);`